# Defining char array based on choice in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, input

I am very new to C++ and have been trying to teach myself for a couple of days now.
I apologize in advanced if my question is obvious or has been asked before, I have searched for a solution a multiple occasions and all the solutions I seem to see are more complex than my gut is telling me I need and generally way over my head... anyway, sorry for the long intro, onto my question:

I'm simply trying to determine the value of (or I guess values... arrays are still a little scary) a wchar_t array (which is just an unicode string?) based on input from a multiple choice question.

Here's what I've come to so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "easendmailobj.tlh"
using namespace EASendMailObjLib;
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int MAX = 65;
//char server[MAX], serverName[MAX], userName[MAX], password[MAX], from[MAX], to[MAX], msg[160];

//Choosing a SMTP server
int choice = 0;
bool logon = true;
bool ssl = true;
cout << "1)Gmail\n"
     << "2)Yahoo\n"
     << "3)Hotmail\n"
     << "4)None (Experemental)\n"
     << "5)Other (Advanced)\n"
     << "What kind of E-mail would you like to send from?:";
cin >> choice;

switch(choice) {
    case 1: wchar_t server[] = _T("smtp.gmail.com");
            char serverName[] = "Gmail";
            break;
    case 2: wchar_t server[] = _T("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
            char serverName[] = "Yahoo";
            ssl = false;
            break;
    case 3: wchar_t server[] = _T("smtp.live.com");
            char serverName[] = "Hotmail";
            break;
    case 4: wchar_t server[] = _T("");
            logon = false;
            ssl = false;
            break;
    case 5: cout << "Enter your server:";
            char server[MAX];
            wcin.getline(server, MAX, '\n');
            cout << "Does your server require a login? (true or false):";
            cin >> logon;
            cout << "Does your server require an SSL connection? (true or false):";
            cin >> ssl;
            break;
    default: cout << endl <<"You entered a wrong number, restart, and try again."
                  << endl;
    }
}
```

This appears to be all fine and dandy but when I try to compile it throws all kinds of errors about declaring the same variable multiple times, which I kind of get but only one of each should ever run based on the choice right? I would declare everything first, and then define based on the choice, but from what I've read that's not possible in C++.

I'm really stuck here, thank you so much in advance for your patience and help.

Comment: Enable all warnings and debugging info in your compiler. Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the case blocks all belong to the same scope.

Even though you have a break between declarations the compiler doesn't care. All it sees is the same variables `server` `serverName` declared multiple times. This is not what you want also because after the switch statement you won't be able to access them.

What you need to do is to declare them before the switch statement and assign them some obviously wrong values (for example `"undefined"`).

Just make sure your default case handles things correctly and you don't continue the execution with the default value you assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest declaring (in your `main` function, or as globals)

```
 std::string server;
 std::string servername;
```

You don't want these variables to be local to each block inside `case`-s.

and coding something like

```
 case 1: server = "smtp.gmail.com";
         servername = "gmail";
         break;
```

You may want to check if a string is empty with e.g. `if (servername.empty())` ...

BTW, you don't seem to code in standard C++: function name `_tmain` is not standard to start with (use `int main(int argc, char**argv)`).

Comment: That _tmain() call is template code with MS Visual C++, which creates Microsoft-specific code by default for console application projects.  That _tmain() entry point and including "stdafx.h" first are mandatory once that project template has been chosen.  VC++ can create standard C++ projects, but there is no built-in template for it.  (...and the express product doesn't support user-defined templates.)  The wchar_t server name makes it look like MS-specific APIs are going to be in use, so this may well be justified.

Comment: First off, Thank you very much for your replies both of you. Mike is correct in that I'm using VC++ and also have some borrowed code further down in the program, specifically involving sending email. Up until now I had assumed it had to do with character set, but what Mike said seems to make a lot of sense to me. If anyone could provide any information about getting between these data types it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't like that you declare the same variables `server` and `serverName` in the same scope (which is the switch scope). Notice that if you add a `{};` around each case block, that would work:

```
case 1: {wchar_t server[] = _T("smtp.gmail.com");
        char serverName[] = "Gmail";
        break;};
```

But then, the variables won't be available outside of each of those scopes. For what you are trying to do, you need to put the variables in the `main` scope and then changing them inside the switch case.

Also, I recommend using strings, as for arrays you need to declare the size right away, or use pointers and malloc inside the switch.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your server and serverName variables.  First, they are defined inside of a switch block and not visible outside the switch block.  Second, they're each defined multiple times in that block.

One way to get this done is to define serverName as a char pointer before the switch block and then use assignment to set in each case clause.  Do the same with the server[] variable:

```
const char *serverName="";
const wchar_t *server = _T("");
switch(choice) {
    case 1: server = _T("smtp.gmail.com");
            serverName = "Gmail";
            break;
    case 2: server = _T("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
            serverName = "Yahoo";
            ssl = false;
            break;
    ...etc.
}
```

Comment: I remember reading something about pointers in my studying but I skimmed over it because it seemed too advanced for me, however it looks to be exactly what I need. I will go back and read about them in more detail but for now the example you have shown me is enough to fix what I need right now and get me going again, thank you very much.

Comment: One thing I noticed wile trying this out is that the "wcin.getline" no longer works, could anyone offer a slight extension on the example above to include that part?

Comment: @Bendude137 you need to use wide char arrays as well as wide char. The end line character must be widened too.